# Is there a more simple sample for Vuforia SDK?

Tags: unity-game-engine, vuforia

I would like to getting started with Vuforia.
The sample app works fine. But there a many classes and i don't get the flow...

Is there a simple sample, without menu, GL rendering and so on? 
Just a sample for the tracker?

Or is there a sequence diagram for the normal sample app?

Comment: What vuforia feature are you using?

Answer (score 0):

- Here is a [tutorial](https://www.sitepoint.com/how-to-build-an-ar-android-app-with-vuforia-and-unity/) with old Unity. The process flow has changed in Unity2017. Here is [image: an old diagram] An old diagram of mine. Hope this help.
- This one is the [setup process](https://library.vuforia.com/articles/Training/getting-started-with-vuforia-in-unity-2017-2-beta.html) with Unity2017.